# Why does my text file outputs sometimes not display?

Tags: python

I am making a simple program to automate using flashcards for sight-reading musical notes, so I'm using text files with ascii art which are then printed in the console for me to read so I don't have to use images. This runs smoothly for a few turns then randomly it will just stop printing the text files contents. I am using 7 text files named A, B, C, D, E, F and G, all of which have content in and will work at the start. The code is as follows:

```
import time
import random
A = open("A.txt","r")
B = open("B.txt","r")
C = open("C.txt","r")
D = open("D.txt","r")
E = open("E.txt","r")
F = open("F.txt","r")
G = open("G.txt","r")
notes = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
i = 1
while i == 1:
 note = random.choice(notes)
 if note == "A":
   print(A.read())
   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET A")
 elif note == "B":
   print(B.read())
   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET B")
 elif note == "C":
   print(C.read())
   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET C")
 elif note == "D":
   print(D.read())
   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET D")
 elif note == "E":
   print(E.read())
   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET E")
 elif note == "F":
   print(E.read())
   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET F")
 else:
   print(F.read())
   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET G")
```

Also I am aware this code can be optimized, but I'm not looking to improve it since this is all I need it for. I am using python 3.9.13.

Comment: Not sure here, but are you getting to the end of one of the files? The file you read from will be picked at random but I believe you're actually reading sequentially through those files.

Comment: Imagine reading a file with your finger as an index. You read file `A` once. Your finger reaches the end of the file. You try to read it a second time, but your finger is already at the end of the file. You didn't set it to the beggining, so you read an empty string. That's whats happening here. Try closing the file and opening it again to solve it.

Comment: close and open file again or run `A.seek(0)`, `B.seek(0)`, etc. to move to the beginning of file.

Comment: code could be simpler if you would keep open files as list - `[A, B, C, ...]` - or you should use `notes` to generate filename and open this file, read it and close it.

Answer (score 1):

After opening file you can read data from file partially - ie. `.read(100)`, `.readline()`. It uses special variable/pointer to remeber where it stoped reading last time and next time it will read new data from this place.

When you read all data then pointer is moved to the end of file and next `read()` tries to get data from the end of file - and it gets empty data.

You may have to close and open again to move pointer to the beginning. Or you can use `A.seek(0)` to move pointer to position `0` in file (which means beginning of file) without closing file.

```
if note == "A":

   print(A.read())  # read all to the end
   A.seek(0)        # move to the beginning

   time.sleep(3)
   print("RESET A")
```

and the same for other files.

---

**EDIT:**

Much simpler

```
import time
import random

notes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

while True:
    note = random.choice(notes)
    
    fh = open(f'{note}.txt')
    print(fh.read())
    fh.close()
    
    time.sleep(3)
    
    print(f"RESET {note}")
```